# What ways are there to paint aluminium panels for outdoor use?

Tags: painting, outdoor, aluminum

I only know of powder coating as a method of applying the final paint.  My questions are:

1. What are other options of painting aluminum panels (e.g. aluminum gate) for outdoor use?
2. How do they compare to powder coating in terms of durability?

Comment: Whether it is spray, roller or brush, the most important is edge preparation and edge paint coverage.

Comment: @SolarMike - what's edge preparation and coverage?

Comment: Maybe it's ensuring the edges are properly prepared for & covered with paint, instead of forgetting about them when working on the big, obvious surface areas?

Comment: When I was in the Air Force zinc chromate primer on the aluminum is what is used on air craft for the primer, there are many types , I found the self etching zinc chromate the best for aluminum then whatever paint you used stuck to the primer. I had an aluminum step van that I used for my scuba business I had painted it with my logo and IQ was used in tough conditions salt water soaked gear and at the coast 30-40 times a year the paint held up quite well even on the inside where gear bumped the walls when turning. So give etching type zinc chromate it works and may be cheaper than powder coat.

Comment: @EdBeal - Very helpful, thanks a lot.  **Question:** What if the aluminium panel is already powdercoated?  Should I apply the primer on the powdercoated paint?  Should I remove it 1st?  Or just paint over the powdercoated paint without a primer?

Comment: If it is already coated the zinc chromate can’t bond with the aluminum so it won’t do any good. Because aluminum oxidizes and most paint won’t bond well with it is the reason to use a primer, powder coating is sprayed and baked it should be as good as a primer.

Comment: @EdBeal "painted it with my logo and IQ was used". What is _IQ_? Is that short for the zinc chromate primer you mentioned earlier?

Comment: I am not sure what IQ (fat finger should be IT )would be, powder coating is usually bead blasted prior to coating then baking, to over lay your logo you will need a paint that can bond with the powder coat something that would bond with porcelain may be an example of the compatible paint types.

Comment: Gotcha, @EdBeal! "typos-be-we" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm just summarising the answer I got from [Ed Beal](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/44366/ed-beal) within the comments, for future reference.*

---

> When I was in the Air Force ***zinc chromate primer*** on the aluminum is
> what is used on air craft for the primer, there are many types , I
> found the self etching zinc chromate the best for aluminum then
> whatever paint you used stuck to the primer. I had an aluminum step
> van that I used for my scuba business I had painted it with my logo
> and it was used in tough conditions salt water soaked gear and at the
> coast 30-40 times a year the paint held up quite well even on the
> inside where gear bumped the walls when turning. So give etching type
> zinc chromate it works and may be cheaper than powder coat.

When I asked [him](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/44366/ed-beal) about the situation where the aluminium panels are already powdercoated, he replied:

> If it is already coated the zinc chromate can’t bond with the aluminum
> so it won’t do any good. Because aluminum oxidizes and most paint
> won’t bond well with it is the reason to use a primer, powder coating
> is sprayed and baked it should be as good as a primer.

Comment: thanks for making an actual answer out of the comments