# Does oil-based paint over powder-coated aluminium benefit from any treatment to reduce bubbles and increase outdoor durability?

Tags: outdoor, oil-based-paint

I have aluminium panels that are powder-coated, and I plan to paint over it with a roller using some oil-based paint.  My questions are:

- **Q1.** Does it matter that what's under the powder-coat is aluminium?  (because the oil paint will only tough the powder-coat layer)
- **Q2.** Is there any treatment that I should do on the powder-coated surface in order to:

  - Reduce bubbles in the oil-based paint.
  - Increase durability/adhesion so that the oil-based paint doesn't peal off in outdoor environments?

This question is a more specific form of [this other question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/232980/what-ways-are-there-to-paint-aluminium-panels-for-outdoor-use?) that further explores the second branch of the answer in the latter question.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to Q2 -

Whether to prevent oxidation of a substrate or to restore cosmetic appearance of your product both are good reasons to apply liquid paint over a powder coated surface, however, you have to do so while paying attention to a few considerations. In this article will cover what you need to consider when applying liquid paint over powder coating. https://pittsburghsprayequip.com/blogs/pittsburgh-spray-equipment-company/paint-over-powder-coating-a-guide

In the article you will find that one very important consideration is the paint to be used shall have similar performance characteristics of the powdered coating, in your case, one additional consideration should be noted that the paint shall be acceptable to the underlying material - aluminum. Please be advised by an experienced paint supplier on this matter.